# How can I DRY this spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How can I DRY this spec? Some custom matchers, shared examples? I never used them, and I will have more code like this for other actions.

```
describe 'Events Permissions' do
  let(:admin) { create(:user_admin) }
  let(:mod) { create(:user_mod) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  let(:link) { create(:link) }
  let(:event) { create(:event) }

  describe 'GET #new' do
    it 'allows admin user to perform action' do
      sign_in admin

      get :new, link: link.id
      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'allows mod user to perform action' do
      sign_in mod

      get :new, link: link.id
      expect(flash[:alert]).to_not match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow user to perform action' do
      sign_in user

      get :new, link: link.id
      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end

    it 'does not allow guest to perform action' do
      get :new, link: link.id
      expect(flash[:alert]).to match(/^You are not authorized to perform this action./)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey! Consider moving the code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, where people may help you refactoring it!

Comment: Thanks for info, didn't know something like this exists.